Create-React-App build - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < and failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-h
enter image description here
Problem: When deploying my app, the build is not working as expected unless I set "homepage": "https://app.netlify.com/" in the package.json.
Is this the correct way to do it, or should I be using a different URL or configuration?
What I Tried: I tried using various configurations in package.json for the homepage field, but this is the only one that seems to work.
Expected Behavior: I expected the app to be accessible on my custom domain (or the provided domain by Netlify/Vercel), but it only works when I set the homepage to the Netlify/Vercel dashboard link.
Actual Behavior: The app doesn't deploy properly or show as expected when the homepage is set incorrectly.

Hey! why do you need to set the homepage in the package.json
